# create multiple corresponding entries in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Three tables:**

- user(id, date)
- item (id, fk_user_id)
- item_history (id, text, fk_item_id)

All users which where created before some specific date need to get a new item.

The data of the item is stored in the item_history 'text' for history purposes.

The text for those new items would be the same for all users.

Since there are quite a lot of users I would need a script which could create new items and corresponding item_histories for all users.

I guess this cannot be done with SQL and my PLSQL knowledge is basically none existent?

I got as far as selecting the users which should get the new items but I have no clue of how to create new items for them and for those items item_histories as well.

Comment: how ho you pupulate the item.id and item_history.id columns? are there sequences defined?

Comment: @schurik yes, sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_ITEM_TEXT(pin_Text IN VARCHAR2) IS
  nItem_id  ITEM.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT ID FROM USER)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO ITEM(ID, FK_USER_ID)
    VALUES (ITEM_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, aRow.ID)
    RETURNING ID INTO nItem_id;

    INSERT INTO ITEM_HISTORY(ID, TEXT, FK_ITEM_ID)
    VALUES (ITEM_HISTORY_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, pin_Text, nItem_id);
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('All changes committed');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || ':' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('All changes ROLLED BACK');
END ADD_USER_ITEM;
```

Since you didn't tell us the names of the sequences to use for the ITEM.ID and ITEM_HISTORY.ID columns I made up sequence names - replace my "made-up" names (ITEM_ID_SEQ for the ITEM table, ITEM_HISTORY_ID_SEQ for the ITEM_HISTORY table) with the correct sequence names.

The above creates a procedure.  To use it you'll need to invoke it as follows:

```
BEGIN
  ADD_ITEM_TEXT('Text for an item');
  ADD_ITEM_TEXT('Text for another item');
  ADD_ITEM_TEXT('Text for the last item');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.